# Visual Studio: Random Number Generator

Tags: visual-studio, random

I'm taking a class and our assignment is the following question. I'm not sure if I'm reading way too much into the question or simply not understanding it. I know how to get the random number setup, but I'm stuck on how to allow the user to specify how many numbers are saved to the file. Any help would be great.

Question:
Write a program that writes a series of random numbers to a file.
Each random number should be in the range of 1 through 100.
The application should let the user specify how many random numbers the file will hold.

This is what I have so far. It works except that the text file only saves the last random number generated instead of all of the random numbers.

```
'using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Random_Number
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Variable
        int result = 0;

        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void generateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get how many random numbers the user wants
            int myRandomNumbers = int.Parse(howManyTextBox.Text);

            // Create the random object
            Random rand = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < myRandomNumbers; i++)
            {
                // Create the list of random numbers
                result = rand.Next(1, 101);

                // Display the random numbers in the ListBox
                randomNumbersListBox.Items.Add(result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void saveAs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         StreamWriter outputFile;

         if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
         {
                 // Create the selected file
                 outputFile = File.CreateText(saveFile.FileName);

                 // Write data to the file
                 outputFile.WriteLine(result);

                 // Close the file
                 outputFile.Close();
         }
         else
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Operation Cancelled");
         }
    }

    private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear the ListBox and TextBox
        howManyTextBox.Text = "";
        randomNumbersListBox.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Close the program
        this.Close();
    }
}
}'
```

Comment: I just am trying to sort out where to go if the user inputs that they want 10 random numbers or 5 random numbers.

Comment: What *type* of program are you writing? The methods of user input vary vastly depending on whether we're talking about a console application, a forms application or a web site.

Comment: Sorry, it's a form application.

Comment: Ok, here's what I have so far. It's working for the most part, but when the user saves a text file, it's only saving the last random number generated instead of all of the numbers generated.

Comment: Step through the code and you will see why only the last number is saved. Hint: The comment "Create the list of random numbers" does not match what the code actually does.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to get it working by adding:
    'foreach (int items in randomNumbersListBox.Text)
     outputFile.WriteLine(items.ToString());
    '

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter count: ");
        var count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Writing numbers... ");
        WriteNumbers(count);
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    }

    static void WriteNumbers(int count)
    {
        var gen = new Random();

        var file = new StreamWriter("YourFile.txt", false);

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            file.Write(gen.Next(1, 100) + " ");
        }

        file.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Help vampires should not be encouraged.